# How to tell that the logon screen is currently displayed?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, winlogon

I am writing a service application that will run with `local system` credentials. I will need to know from my service if the Windows logon screen is displayed at any particular time. Is there any way to do this?

PS. The screens that can be brought up by locking the workstation:

[image]

Or by trying to switch the user:

[image]

Or after a Ctrl+Alt+Del:

[image]

PS. I need this to run on Windows XP and up.

**EDIT:** The only viable solution that I came up with so far is to see if `LogonUI.exe` process is running. The issue with this approach is how to distinguish between the actual system logon process and any other process that has that image name?

Comment: Why do you want to know this

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: So that my user-mode process doesn't bother with displaying user messages since a user won't see them.

Comment: @c00000fd: Your service shouldn't show messages anyway. The conventional solution is a small app which talks to your service; the app can trivially find out if it's visible.

Comment: @MSalters: You want to show me how will your app determine if it's visible? PS. Btw, I'm not saying that I'm displaying messages from the service.

Comment: `IsWindowVisible(HWND)`

Comment: If `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` doesn't give you the information you need, I believe `OpenInputDesktop` is the most reliable method.

Comment: @MSalters: `IsWindowVisible` deals with `WS_VISIBLE` style and has nothing to do with determining whether a window is currently viewable by an end-user.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the comments you are trying to detect whether or not a process in an interactive desktop session should show a message box. There being no point doing so if the interactive session is not active.

In which case I believe that your proposed solution is the wrong one. Instead you should register for session change notifications by calling `WTSRegisterSessionNotification`. When you do this you'll get sent `WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE` messages that allow you to keep track of the current state.

Note that you do this in your desktop app rather than the service. The service still sends its messages to the desktop app. But the desktop app now knows whether or not it is worth showing them.

**Update**

Remy suggests a better way in the comments:

> And if a separate app is being used, there is no reason to detect session changes at all, that app can simply check if its currently assigned workstation/desktop is the currently interactive workstation/desktop instead, comparing `GetThreadDesktop()` to `OpenInputDesktop()`, for instance.

Comment: Will those notifications be sent out for a Ctrl+Alt+Del window, or a lock screen (when a user locks the workstation)?

Comment: Yes they will. Read the docs for the message. It lists all the events.

Comment: I must be not seeing it but where is the Ctrl+Alt+Del notification?

Comment: Not sure. Try it and see what you get sent.

Comment: Services can receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` notifications directly in their `HandlerEx()` callback. There is no need for a separate app just for that purpose.

Comment: @RemyLebeau there is already a separate app as I understand it. After all, what else is going to display windows on the user desktop?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: A service can display messages to user using either `MessageBox(MB_SERVICE_NOTIFICATION)` and/or `WTSSendMessage()` without involving a separate app at all.  And if a separate app is being used, there is no reason to detect session changes at all, that app can simply check if its currently assigned workstation/desktop is the currently interactive workstation/desktop instead, comparing `GetThreadDesktop()` to `OpenInputDesktop()`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

All such screens are presented on a separate desktop. You may try to [enumerate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the user's desktops and compare it with the current (I am not sure the service in session 0 - Vista and up - can do that; if not, spawn a helper process in the user session). This however may give a false positive if an UAC desktop is up. Another corner case is a userless situation (right after boot before any user looged on).

Comment: `EnumDesktops` won't enumerate them across sessions, so it won't work.

Comment: @c00000fd: at some point, you're going to have to accept that some of your code is going to have to run inside the user's session.  You can't always do everything directly from the service process.  Launching a separate process and using IPC is awkward, but sometimes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

There are several states in the windows.

1. Logged-Off State

When Winlogon is in the logged-off state, users are prompted to identify themselves and provide authentication information. If a user provides correct user account information and no restrictions prevent it, the user is logged on and a shell program (such as Windows Explorer) is executed in the application desktop. Winlogon changes to the logged-on state.

2. Logged-On State

When Winlogon is in the logged-on state, users can interact with the shell, activate additional applications, and do their work. From the logged-on state, users can either stop all work and log off, or lock their workstations (leaving all work in place). If the user decides to log off, Winlogon will terminate all processes associated with that logon session and the workstation will be available for another user. If, instead, the user decides to lock the workstation, Winlogon changes to the workstation-locked state.

3. Workstation-Locked State

When Winlogon is in the workstation-locked state, a secure desktop is displayed until the user unlocks the workstation by providing the same identification and authentication information as the user who originally logged on, or until an administrator forces a logoff. If the workstation is unlocked, the application desktop is displayed, and work can resume.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/aa380547(v=vs.85).aspx

p.s. registering a secure attention sequence (SAS, CTRL+ALT+Delete) is included in Workstation-Locked state

Similarly, there are several desktop types on windows.

1. Winlogon desktop
2. Application desktop(=Default desktop)
3. Screensaver desktop
4. Secure desktop

I recommend you read this: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/library/windows/desktop/aa375994(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know my answers are what you want... but I hope it helps in some ways.