# How to get the Active Desktop type on windows?

Tags: c++, session, desktop, messagebox, winlogon

My software (a service coded in cpp) needs to know which desktop is active currently:

1. Winlogon desktop
2. Application desktop
3. Screen saver desktop

I have the code for registering WTS_SESSION_CHANGE but that only works when the session is switched. 
Is there any way to know after power-on if the current screen is still WinLogon?

The purpose of this is to display a Messagebox in the correct desktop through a child process in user mode.

Comment: I looked at this thread, but it didn't help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147872/how-to-tell-that-the-logon-screen-is-currently-displayed

Comment: Have a read of: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Got the solution.. comparing the names of GetThreadDesktop() with OpenInputDesktop() worked.

Answer (score 3):

Got the solution.. comparing the names of GetThreadDesktop() with OpenInputDesktop() worked (inside the user process).